# Access SharePoint Folder using Service account

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint folder where the url looks like: "team..com/sites//Documentation/Forms/All items.aspx
Now the requirement is to access this url using a service account and Django.
Can you help me a way?
Thanks in advance

We have looked for different cases but haven't been successful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the organization-level external sharing setting in [Sharing in the SharePoint admin center](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2185222). And you will need admin permissions for your organization.

Under External sharing, specify your sharing level for SharePoint and OneDrive like following

[image]

Then you can share the folder with external users

[image]